# How to return human readable http response using Rest-Client in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, irb, rest-client

I am just learning the basics of the rest-client gem for ruby and have been submitting various http requests in irb to learn how it works.

Is there a way of having the HTTP response body display in a human readable format?

Also is there a way to return the HTTP response header as well as the body?

Comment: What do you mean, "human readable format"?

Comment: You can try `html_safe`, to remove all `HTML` markup

    `response.body.html_safe`

Comment: By human readable I mean that when it is returned to the command line the markup can be read on seperate lines rather than all being returned on one long line. I dont know if this is possible without saving it to a file though

Comment: what kind of content is it? html? json? xml?

Comment: its HTML, I was just loading simple HTML pages to get a feel for how it worked. But its practically impossible to read even simple websites HTML when it is all returned on one line